# Neo4j something similar SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, neo4j, graph-databases, ssms

just a question about Neo4j and graph databases: Is there something similar like SQL Server Management Studio from Microsoft?

Background information: I have to compare SQL vs graph databases for study. For the practical section I need to implement a friend structure (of social networks) for sql and (I chosen) Neo4j. I just want to compare the speed of both dbs (performance test). So if I execute a query I need the execution time - and I know SQL Server Management Studio does this.

Or has someone any other solution/idea for comparison? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are testing. If you are testing Cypher execution speed (which is not optimized for performance yet), then you get timings with the result set. Otherwise, you could implement an unmanaged extension that measures queries as they come in and get executed, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-unmanaged-extensions.html .